# django-tenants example 404 error, run through the tutorial video twice and keep getting the same error

Tags: python, django

This is from the tutorial video from Tom - I ran through it twice :

```
http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/
Raised by:  customers.views.TenantView

http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/admin
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/admin

http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/admin/
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://t1.dtdemo.local:8000/admin/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.sites.index
```

Settings.py

```py
"""

Django settings for dtdemo2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

SHARED_APPS = [

    'django_tenants',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'customers'

]
TENANT_APPS=[
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'myclientapp'
]

INSTALLED_APPS=list(set(SHARED_APPS + TENANT_APPS))
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'dtdemo2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dtdemo2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': '***',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TENANT_MODEL = "customers.Client"
TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL="customers.Domain"
DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version' : 1,
    'filters': {
        'tenant_context': {
            '()': 'django_tenants.log.TenantContextFilter'
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'tenant_context': {
            'format': '[%(schema_name)s:%(domain_url)s] '
            '%(levelname)-7s %(asctime)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['tenant_context'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter' : 'tenant_context'
        },
    },
}
```

etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t1.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t2.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t3.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t4.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t5.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t6.dtdemo.local
127.0.0.1   t7.dtdemo.local

127.0.0.1   dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t1.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t2.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t3.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t4.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t5.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t6.dtdemo2.local
127.0.0.1   t7.dtdemo2.local
```

Comment: What does your urls.py look like?

Comment: """dtdemo URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]

Comment: I cleaned up my python and Django installs and re-started. The error has seemed to clear up. Thanks.